# JQuery Autocomplete Problem

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI Autocomplete in my JSP. Whenever user keys character, i made the request to server and get the data as JSON and load with the pulgin.

It's working fine. But Whenever i typed the same character as previous term. It's not populating any values.

For eg., First i typed p, it lists the p starting elements. I have the button to reset the text content of autocompleter. After reset, if i am typing same character p, it doesn't show anything.

my code as follows,

```
var cache = {};

   $("#Name").autocomplete({  
             source: function(req, add){
      if (req.term in cache) {
                 add(cache[req.term]);
                 return;
             }
     $.getJSON("/store/StockManagement?action=getMedicinesStock",req, function(data) {  
                  var medicines = [];  
                  $.each(data, function(i, val){  
                   medicines.push(val.name + "," + val.code);
             });

             cache[req.term] = medicines;  
             add(medicines);  
         });  
     },select: function(e, ui) {  
         var medicine = ui.item.value;
         $('#Code').val(medicine.split(",")[1]);
         setTimeout(function(){
             var med = $('#Name').val();
             $('#Name').val(med.split(",")[0]);
         },500);
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Taken from jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js
if (a.term != a.element.val()) { // *** THE MATCH IS HERE
    //console.log("a.term != a.element.val(): "+a.term+", "+a.element.val());
    a.selectedItem = null;
    a.search(null, c) // *** SEARCH IS TRIGGERED HERE
}
```

I just commented the condition. now it's works fine.